# How to unmarshall a ReponseEntity Object returned by RestTemplate?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have two third party API's which I'm hitting and getting the response as `ResponseEntity<Object>` using RestTemplate. I want to unmarshal the response into objects so that I can access the content inside of it.

```
ResponseEntity<Object> response = restTemplate.exchange(apiEndPointToHit,HttpMethod.GET,null,Object.class);
```

**1st API Response**

```
    {
        "responseStatus": "SUCCESS",
        "size": 88,
        "start": 0,
        "limit": 200,
        "sort": "id asc",
        "users": [
            {
                "user": {
                    "user_name": "XYZ",
                    "user_first_name": "XYZ",
                    "user_last_name: "XYZ",
                    "user_email": "XYZ",
                  }
            },

           {
                "user":{
                   "user_name":"ABC",
                   "user_first_name":"ABC",
                   "user_last_name":"ABC",
                 },
             },

             {
               "user":{
                   "user_name":"PQR",
                   "user_first_name":"PQR",
                   "user_last_name":"PQR",
                }
             },

           }
         ]
    }
```

In this response, users will contain multiple user. I want to get list of all user. So that I can access the content of each user object inside that list fields like user_name, user_first_name, etc.

**2nd API response is**

```
{
  "message": {
    "documents": {
   }
 }
}
```

In this case, one message will have one document. I want to access the document.
JSON responses contain multiple fields. So it is not possible to create a POJO class.
Is there any way to access the Objects inside response entity with creating POJO classes?

Comment: To be honest, your first api response seems veeeeeeryyyyyy suspicious - You have "users" - which is an array, fine - of 1! object, containing 3x same field "user"....

Comment: @Worthless Thanks for pointing this out. I have updated my question

Answer (score 1):

We can use either Object mapper or JSONObject which helps to deserialize the JSON body. I would suggest to use JSONObject and following the below example to unmarshall jsonbody.

**1. Add Dependency**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20180130</version>
</dependency>
```

2. Initialize the JSONObject passing the jsonReponse from the restTemplate.

```
JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
```

3. Try acceessing the objects in jsonResponse by just doing

```
getJsonObject/getJsonArray

JSONArray ja = jo.getJsonArray("users");
```